# Check content type when file is done downloading nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am using a nsurlsession to manage downloading image/video files. Trouble is sometimes the request goes bad and returns text like "Content not found." How can I make sure that the file thats being downloaded is actually the file type I requested? (such as .jpeg or .mp4)

Comment: Might help to inspect a few bytes first, for the magic headers for the file types, once that passes the test, then attempt to load it using UIImage, it will fail in that regard if the image is corrupted. Then again, overall, if there's a bad request, a retry would be recommended or discard it.Also, if content is not found, its more of a server side that you need to account for as well.

Comment: How would I inspect the bytes for the headers? Also i'm ok with downloading it all and then looking at the headers. I am storing them in a caches directory so would it be best to read from an nsurl to see the headers?

Comment: Ok, since storing them in the caches directory, open the file and read the first twenty bytes at the most, to determine the file type that is actually a image/video file. Again, should there not be a mechanism on the server side to ensure the media content is validated and stored prior to attempting to download? Are you making REST api requests to some backend - php or similar? Please include the vital information for others.

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it figured out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check inside `URLSessionDataDelegate` method `didReceive response` the response property `mimeType` and check if it is `"image/jpg"`:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        if response.mimeType == "image/jpg" || response.mimeType == "image/jpeg" {
            completionHandler(.becomeDownload)
        } else {
            // your code when it is not jpeg
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version**

```
guard let httpUrlResponse = sessionTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
    return
    
}
guard let mimeType = httpUrlResponse.mimeType else {
    return
}
```